# How to use delete statement inside a function in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
delimiter //  
create function kill_aliens (rand int)

begin 

if rand <= 0.2 and rand >= 0 then  
delete from alienkilling limit 2 where dtypeid = 11;

elseif rand <=0.75 and rand > 0.2 then  
delete from alienkilling limit 3 where dtypeid = 12;

else rand <=1 and rand >0.75 then    
delete from alienkilling limit 1 where dtypeid = 13;

end if; //
```

It gives me a syntax error

Comment: Post the error message in your question. It will indicate where the syntax error is located.

Comment: At first brush, `else rand <=1 and rand >0.75 then` this doesn't make sense. Perhaps you mean `elseif`

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin 
 
 if rand <= 0.2 and rand >= 0 then
 delete from alienkilling limit 2 where' at line 3 0.000 sec
@BurhanKhalid

Comment: Does function supports DELETE Statement?

Comment: @JaydipJ yes, it does. Any sql statement DDL, DML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your function definition lets list then:

1 - You are creating a function, therefore it needs a `returns` declaration

2 - Your deletes commands are with wrong syntax, `limit` should be the last clause (between, makes no sense a limit in a delete although it works)

3 - There is no `THEN` for the `ELSE` statement and also `else` doesn't take conditions, it should be another `ELSEIF`

4 - If it is a function you need to `return` something

5 - You didn't ended your function with an `end` statement

So it should be like:

```
delimiter //  
create function kill_aliens (rand int) returns int
begin 
    if rand <= 0.2 and rand >= 0 then  
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 11 limit 2;
    elseif rand <=0.75 and rand > 0.2 then  
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 12 limit 3;
    elseif rand <=1 and rand >0.75 then    
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 13 limit 1;
    end if;

    return 0; -- it must be some value
end //
delimiter ;
```

Side notes: Learn how to indent your code. If this would not return anything it should be a procedure not a function.

Something like:

```
delimiter //  
create procedure kill_aliens (rand int)
begin 
    if rand <= 0.2 and rand >= 0 then  
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 11 limit 2;
    elseif rand <=0.75 and rand > 0.2 then  
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 12 limit 3;
    elseif rand <=1 and rand >0.75 then    
        delete from alienkilling where dtypeid = 13 limit 1;
    end if;
end //
delimiter ;
```